# ssh agent forwarding on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssh

When I ssh from my macOS client with `AgentForwarding` enabled into a Windows 10 host, I cannot access the client keys on the host.

The built-in OpenSSH server on the Windows host has `AllowAgentForwarding` enabled.

Also, agent forwarding works correctly when I ssh into other (non-windows) hosts.

Is there some special trick I'm missing to get agent forwarding working on a Windows host, or what could be causing it not to work.

The debug log at least seems to indicate that it's trying to connect the agent:

```
debug1: active: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request auth-agent req@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req auth-agentreq@openssh.com
```

Comment: I'm attempting to do the same, and for me it's not working either. Try: `ssh -vvv <user@host>`. When I try that, I'm seeing:

`debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding not supported in Windows yet`

in the output. I've tried using instructions from 
[Installation of OpenSSH For Windows Server 2019 and Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)
and then  installed OpenSSH with `choco install openssh`. Couldn't make it work either way.

Comment: Were you able to to solve the problem @WojciechA.Koszek / matthew? If yes, please answer here or at https://superuser.com/questions/1724001/ssh-agent-forwarding-not-working-on-windows. thx!

Comment: There seems to be still no support for SSH agent forwarding in Windows, as of Mid'2022: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1865

Answer (score 3):

SSH Agent Forwarding was not included in the original scope of work for the Windows OpenSSH project (see the [Project Scope](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Project-Scope) wiki page, which refers to this feature as "Authentication Forwarding").

However, it looks like this feature will be addressed in a future release. The [vNext](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/milestone/40) milestone includes several references to agent forwarding issues:

- [debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding not supported in Windows yet](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1461)
- [Agent Forwarding Windows client to Windows host not working?](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1865)
- [Support ssh agent restrictions](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1902)

Answer (score -1):

On Windows 11, at least, you can SSH Agent forwarding is avaialable, but you need to run the ssh authentication agent:

1. Open the 'Services' application from the Start menu.
2. Scroll down to 'OpenSSH Authentication Agent'.
3. Right-click the service to access its 'Properties'. Change its 'Startup type' to 'Automatic (Delayed Start)'. 'OK' to save your change.
4. Right-click the service and choose 'Start' from the context menu.

Answer (score -3):

SSH-Agent is disabled by default on windows.

From [[OpenSSH key management][1] article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement)

```
# By default the ssh-agent service is disabled. Allow it to be manually started for the next step to work.
# Make sure you're running [Powershell] as an Administrator.
Get-Service ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Manual

# Start the service
Start-Service ssh-agent

# This should return a status of Running
Get-Service ssh-agent

# Now load your key files into ssh-agent
ssh-add ~\.ssh\id_ed25519
```

Comment: The question is not about how to enable ssh-agent, but how to use agent **forwarding**.