# ssh agent forwarding not working on Windows

Tags: windows-10, openssh, windows-11, ssh-agent, configure

Same ask as [ssh agent forwarding on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1452861/ssh-agent-forwarding-on-windows-10), but on Windows 11.

When I ssh from my Linux client with `AgentForwarding` enabled into a Windows 11 host, I cannot access the client keys on the host:

```
C:\Users\admin>ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

The built-in OpenSSH server on the Windows host has `AllowAgentForwarding` enabled.

Also, agent forwarding works correctly when I ssh into other (non-windows) hosts.

Is there some special trick I'm missing to get agent forwarding working on a Windows host, or what could be causing it not to work.

The debug log at least seems to indicate that it's trying to connect the agent:

```
debug1: active: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request auth-agent req@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req auth-agentreq@openssh.com
```

More info,

Should I configure OpenSSH Authentication Agent service to automatically start?

https://superuser.com/a/1354118/203539 says

> You must

But I saw later there is a warning:

> I must warn you **against** using ssh-agent from the PowerShell port
> of openssh as it silently uses ondisk storage of your keys in the
> Registry. See my own question (and answer)
> [where-does-windows-openssh-ssh-agent-service-secretly-store-private-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65629402/where-does-windows-openssh-ssh-agent-service-secretly-store-private-keys)
> for a full explanation.
>
> Essentially there are 3 problems with it:
>
> 1. It stores secret keys ON DISK - never use in a shared or guest situation
> 2. (traces of) Secret keys remain ON DISK after deletion
> 3. PoweShell implementation does not conform to the openssh manual page ssh-agent.1 in key aspects of security.

Not sure if it is the same thing though.

Comment: FYI: Whatever the solution might actually be to to this problem, absolutely would apply to Windows 10 21H2 and Windows 11 21H2, since the same version of OpenSSH Server is on both versions of Windows.

Comment: Just out of interest, in the unlikely even this is a tracked issue, what version of OpenSSH Server is actually installed?